# how to get Selected Value from Dropdownlist on update record in Angularjs?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel, selected

I filled my dropdownlist by angular js from json. But selection is not working on update i can not get selected value . How can i select dropdownlist selected item?

```
//get single record by ID
$scope.getForUpdate = function (Branch) {
    debugger        
    var getData = myService.getBrancheTypes();
    getData.then(function (response) {
        debugger
        $scope.BrancheTypes = response.data;            
    }, function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        toastr.error("Error in getting records.");
    });
    debugger
    $scope.Branch_ID = Branch.Branch_ID;
    $scope.Branch_Name = Branch.Branch_Name;
    $scope.Branch_Address = Branch.Branch_Address;
    $scope.Branch_email = Branch.Branch_email;
    $scope.Branch_Notes = Branch.Branch_Notes;
    $scope.Branch_TimeFrom = new Date(moment(Branch.Branch_TimeFrom));
    $scope.Branch_TimeTo = new Date(moment(Branch.Branch_TimeTo));
    $scope.Branch_CreatedDate = new Date(moment(Branch.Branch_CreatedDate));
    $scope.Branch_Manager = Branch.Branch_Manager;
    $scope.Branch_TypeId = Branch.Branch_TypeId; // Branch.Branch_TypeId = 1
    $scope.Branch_Type = $scope.BrancheTypes[Branch.Branch_Type]; // Object {BranchTypeId: 1, BranchTypeName: "Head Office", Branches: null}     
    $scope.Branch_Phone = Branch.Branch_Phone;
    $scope.Branch_Fax = Branch.Branch_Fax;
    $scope.saturday = Branch.saturday;
    $scope.sunday = Branch.sunday;
    $scope.monday = Branch.monday;
    $scope.tuesday = Branch.tuesday;
    $scope.wednesday = Branch.wednesday;
    $scope.thursday = Branch.thursday;
    $scope.friday = Branch.friday;        
};
```

```html
<select ng-model="Branch_Type">
   <option value="{{field.BranchTypeId}}" ng-selected="true"
           ng-repeat="field in BrancheTypes | orderBy:'BranchTypeId'">
     {{field.BranchTypeName}}
   </option>
</select>
```

this is the values on debug

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yqkb5.png)

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing your html to this

```
<select ng-model="selectedDevice" 
        ng-options="field.BranchTypeId as field.BranchTypeName for field in BrancheTypes | orderBy:'BranchTypeId'">
    <option></option>
</select>
```